# Angular Js Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in using angular js and I just can't find what's going wrong.It gives these errors:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]           http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=rest&p1=Error%3A%20…   ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4470n @ angular.js:341g @ angular.js:4431db @ angular.js:4356c @ angular.js:1677zc @ angular.js:1698ce @ angular.js:1592(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29652b @ angular.js:3069Of @ angular.js:3358Nf.d @ angular.js:3346`

Here is my code in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pC9zJkdnwJNGyL7phPY0?p=preview)

Comment: 1st thing you missed to add `ngResource` files, other than that you had injected `rest.filters` & `rest.directives` module, which haven;t been defined yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of mistakes:

1) while referring to js files in plunker , don't give `/controllers.js` instead give `controllers.js`

2) for loading js files, you have specified `type="app.js"` instead of `src="app.js"`

```
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

3) you forgot to load `ng-resource.js`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

4) the config section with the route provider was not correct. the syntax was wrong.

This is correct:

```
rest.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/index', {templateUrl: 'index.html', controller: 'taskListCtrl'}).
        when('/account', {templateUrl: 'account.html', controller: 'accountListCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});
    }])
```

5) you need to load `controllers.js` and `services.js` before `app.js`

6) you can't have dependency on modules that do not exist, like `rest.filters` and `rest.directives`

```
var rest = angular.module('rest', ['ngRoute', 'rest.services','rest.controllers']);
```

Here is the updated plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hTCnNaXgCAKUUPCXrIT3?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your controller function definition for the first controller in the controller.js file is wrong. Check the services you are injecting into the controller, the ones in the square bracket do not match the function arguments.